# Pandas rolling window cumsum, with incomplete series

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
YEAR   MONTH   USERID    TRX_COUNT
2020   1        1         1
2020   2        1         2
2020   3        1         1
2020   12       1         1
2021   1        1         3
2021   2        1         3
2021   3        1         4
```

I want to `sum` the `TRX_COUNT` such that, each `TRX_COUNT` is the `sum` of `TRX_COUNTS` of the next 12 months.
So my end result would look like

```
YEAR   MONTH   USERID    TRX_COUNT   TRX_COUNT_SUM
2020   1        1         1            5
2020   2        1         2            7
2020   3        1         1            8
2020   12       1         1            11
2021   1        1         3            10
2021   2        1         3            7
2021   3        1         4            4
```

For example `TRX_COUNT_SUM` for `2020/1` is `1+2+1+1=5` the count of the first 12 months.
Second entry is 7 as it is the sum of `2+1+1+3` which is 12 months from `2020/2`
I do expect partials, where there is not a full year of data. These can be either summed up partially or set to zero (as I wont be using partials).
I tried various variations of `cumsum` and grouping by `USERID, YR, MONTH` but am running into errors with handling the time window.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the logic and expected output, you are looking for more of rolling sum than cumsum. You want to roll 12 months and sum the number of `TRX_COUNT`. `cumsum` would cumulatively adding up the previous calculations.

Anyway, a few things that is complicated in your dataset. 1. interval is uneven 2. You are looking for forward rolling and typical rolling is backward.

To solve this, first, I would make the interval even so that I can use regular rolling.

```py
df['ym'] = pd.to_datetime([f'{x}/0{y}' if y < 10 else f'{x}/{y}' for x, y in zip(df.YEAR, df.MONTH)])
df = df.set_index('ym').resample('MS').first()
```

Then, try forward rolling. To do the forward rolling, I reverse the dataframe once and do rolling then reverse back.

```py
df['TRX_COUNT_SUM'] = (df.iloc[::-1]    # Reverse to do (backward) rolling
                       .rolling(12, min_periods=0)
                       .TRX_COUNT.sum()
                       .iloc[::-1])     # Reverse back to original

# remove resampled records
df = df[df.YEAR > 0]
```

Result.

```
              YEAR  MONTH  USERID  TRX_COUNT  TRX_COUNT_SUM
ym
2020-01-01  2020.0    1.0     1.0        1.0            5.0
2020-02-01  2020.0    2.0     1.0        2.0            7.0
2020-03-01  2020.0    3.0     1.0        1.0            8.0
2020-12-01  2020.0   12.0     1.0        1.0           11.0
2021-01-01  2021.0    1.0     1.0        3.0           10.0
2021-02-01  2021.0    2.0     1.0        3.0            7.0
2021-03-01  2021.0    3.0     1.0        4.0            4.0
```